# FB like box for org page not loading

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-likebox

I recently set up a Facebook page for my organization. Myself and the communications person at my organization have tried to set up a FB like box for my organization's website. When I go through the steps logged in as an organization page, it says I have to switch from using FB as a page to using it as a personal account. When I do that, and go through the steps again, the FB like box is generated correctly. When I take IFRAME text and generate it into HTML, it does not load, nothing shows up. I'm thinking that this is a permission issue or some else...not sure how to fix.

Comment: Do you have any code for us to look at?

Comment: This is what was generated...we did not change it all:

http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7839303/facebook-like-button-script-for-off-site-not-working-in-any-of-the-options-html

Comment: @Aldwoni You should maybe have used [tag:facebook-likebox] for this one.

Answer (score 0):

Are you removing the iFrame from the markup? This is an essential part of the like box, and it won't work without it. Seeing some of your markup vs their markup would be awesome. :)

**Edit**:

I can't tell what the difference is, because I don't have a diff tool handy right now, but here's a JS fiddle where yours doesn't work, and the code I regenerated based on yours does 
work.

http://jsfiddle.net/XrSKx/

Comment: This is what was generated: 

<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fwashingtonaidspartnership&amp;width=350&amp;colorscheme=dark&amp;show_faces=true&amp;border_color&amp;stream=true&amp;header=true&amp;height=590" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:350px; height:590px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>